# How to send twillio SMS using alphanumeric caller id

Tags: twilio, sms, alphanumeric

We have registered 7 international numbers in Twilio to send SMS.
We would like to use different sender ID.
For example Germany don't need any approvement.
How can I send SMS with "ABCDEF" sender ID for this German number?
We have enabled alphanumeric caller id in Twilio account.
c# example is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation:

[Alphanumeric Sender ID for Twilio Programmable SMS](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS)

> To get a dynamic Sender ID: If pre-registration is not required, you
> can instantly get a Sender ID.
>
> Simply add the Sender ID you want in the From parameter in line 4 of
> the cURL script, as shown in the example below:

```
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json \
-d "Body=Hello from my phone number" \
-d "To=+12685551234" \
-d "From=ALPHA" \
-u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'
```